# Вертикальное меню: проблема с кодом

Tags: jquery

А вопрос вот такой. Делаю меню вертикальное... задумка (при наведении на одну из этих ссылок(кнопок) рядом с ней должна плавно появляться стрелочка, но у меня они сразу все вылезают для всех ссылок (кнопок). Код ниже

```
<div class="navigation-text-menu_head">
    <img style="position:absolute; margin-left:-2px;" src="images/block_menu.png">Меню</div>
    <div id="navigation-text-menu">
        <ul>
            <style type="text/css">
                #navigation-text-menu {
                    background: #2b2a2a;
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    height: 230px;
                    margin-left: -3px;
                    margin-top: 9px;
                    width: 275px;
                }
                #navigation-text-menu ul {
                    list-style: none;
                }
                #navigation-text-menu li {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #676665;
                    margin-left: -40px;
                }
                #navigation-text-menu li a {
                    background: #2b2a2a;
                    color: #fff;
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    padding: 9px 9px 10px 15px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                #navigation-text-menu ul li img {
                    display: none;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#navigation-text-menu ul li a').hover(function () {
                        $(this).fadeIn('fast', function () {
                            $('#navigation-text-menu ul li img').fadeIn(10000);
                        }).animate({
                            backgroundColor: "#165b95",
                            paddingLeft: '50px'
                        }, 500);
                    }, function () {
                        $(this).animate({
                            backgroundColor: "#2b2a2a",
                            paddingLeft: 15
                        }, 500);
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow-menu.png">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow-menu.png">Руководства</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow-menu.png">Файлы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow-menu.png">Серверы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow-menu.png">Форум</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/arrow-menu.png">Турниры</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: если что не так подправьте
тут конечно больше сделано то что я писал(анимация блока движение ссылки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
$('#navigation-text-menu ul li img').fadeIn(10000);
```

на

```
$('img',this).fadeIn(10000);
```

Comment: попробую спасибо

Comment: спасибо мэн работает